Young Adult Novel In which character has the ability to cause chain reactions of violence
The story in question has the protagonist(?) Start a chain reaction in a neighborhood that leads to the whole area devolving into anarchy with people killing each other. This character may or may not be compelled to do this act.
In what may be the same story, earlier, the character felt compelled to commit an act of destruction, after which they went to a priest to confess their actions, to which the priest said they could not forgive it.
There might have also been other characters that had powers with drawbacks. I think at one point all of the drawbacks got combined into one person - one of said drawbacks being obesity, or high weight.

In roughly which year did you read this?

2019-2020, I believe
